# Google Screen Sharing Technology

Tags: javascript, google-hangouts, screensharing

What technology do Google use for their Hangouts Screen Sharing?

I've searched for a million times about it. Is it WebRTC? I think no! If it is, Why don't I need to enable a certain settings in `chrome://flags` (in Google Chrome) for it to work?

Comment: its the same technology desktop sharing apps use. it basically uses javascript to capture the screen. can be done easily using webkit. try this http://ctrlq.org/code/19136-screenshots-javascript or http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:m3OhCr7C_xgJ:ctrlq.org/code/19136-screenshots-javascript+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in&client=firefox-a

Comment: when that page says "Chrome privileges" that means its a chrome extension can do it, but a web page can't.

Comment: but google's screen sharing can capture the whole screen, not just a web page or a tab.